# How to read TLS extension types in dotnet core 3.1?

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-core, tls1.2, tls1.3

A third party gateway is adding a custom TLS extension type ([TLS Extension Types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-extensiontype-values/tls-extensiontype-values.xhtml)) and we have to read the incoming extension type value in dotnet core 3.1 web application.

I cant seem to find any documentation related to this apart from getting hostname from SNI using ITlsHandshakeFeature (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Servers/Connections.Abstractions/src/Features/ITlsHandshakeFeature.cs)

[image: Incoming Extension Types]

I tried going through the server features available in dotnet core but none of them have a way of accessing the extension types. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Core 3.1 does not support all encryption modes and probably will not work with TLS 1.3.  The kludge in the past was to use OpenSSL to perform encryption.

Comment: I don't think SChannel on Windows even provides this info.